# What is the last element of the output of keras.model.evaluate()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I've made a network with two sets of outputs and used the `accuracy` metric. When I use `self.model.evaluate(...)`, it returns a tuple with length of 5. Based on the keras documentation, I think the outputs are:

```
(loss_first_output, acc_first_output, loss_second_output, acc_second_output, ...)
```

But what is the fifth element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://keras.io/models/model/#model-class-api) `model.metrics_names` will provide you the names of metrics.